# Substituting one node for another

Tags: jaxb, docx, docx4j

I'm using docx4j, which uses JAXB.

I want to change a Text node to be a Paragraph node (or delete/add in the same place).

This may be more of a JAXB question .. I'm not familiar with it.

I can find the relevant Text node using

```
MainDocumentPart.getJAXBNodesViaXpath()
```

Looking at samples, I can see how to create a new paragraph node.
However, from there, I'm lost.  Not sure how to delete the Text node that I find, and how to insert a new paragraph node at that position (or -- if it's better -- how to "change" the Text node into a Paragraph node).